# Enter specific text into textbox and add +1 to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I'm new to excel but now i'm stuck at something.
The one thing i try to achieve is that if i add a specific word into a textbox, another cell gets +1 (so if 0 and text has been entered in the textbox, it changes to 1 etc.)
so for example:

Cell B2 = Apple

Cell H2 : value of B2

I'd like to get, if possible, one or two textboxes where i could put the type of product and another box for the amount.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `TextBox2.Value = IIf(Len(TextBox1.Value),1,"")`. It would make TextBox2 blank if TextBox1 is blank and show a "1" there if anything is entered in TextBox1.

Comment: It has to work as counting up. When, in this example, I have 5 apples and if i put 'Apple' in the textbox, it will count 1 up, so to 6 and so on.

Comment: How to make sense of that? You first enter "apple" and Tbx2 becomes 1. Then you write "Pear" and Tbx2 becomes 2. Is that what you want? Where is your Tbx? Is it an ActiveX control on a worksheet? Is it on a user form?

Comment: No no, probably i gave a wrong explanation. See it as a list of products. 
Cell A1 = Apple       Cell B1 is the total of the amount of apples
Cell A2 = Pear         Cell B2 is the total of the amount of pears
etc....

 So if you have a big list of products, it's easier to have a textbox where you just have to put the name of the product and the amount you've got. you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here's a solution.

1. Set up a named range. I entered 5 different fruit in one column and 5 different quantities in the adjacent column (doesn't matter where but must be adjacent). I named the range "Products" but any other name will do just as well.
2. I set up a data validation list. I used cell G3 but any other will be equally suitable. I pointed the data validation list to `=INDEX(Products,0,1)`, meaning the first column of the `Products` range.
3. Now I added code to the worksheet. This code must be in the code sheet of the *worksheet* on which G3 is located. That code sheet will have a name like *Sheet1 (Sheet1)*. Don't use a standard code module with a name like *Module1*. Here is the code.

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       ' 018

   ```
   Const Trigger = "G3"                ' change to suit
   Dim Qty As Long

   With Target
       If .Address = Range(Trigger).Address Then
           On Error Resume Next            ' in case not found
           Qty = Application.VLookup(.Value, Range("Products"), 2, False)
           .Offset(0, 1).Value = Qty + 1
       End If
   End With
   ```

   End Sub

Note that the *Trigger* cell is named as "G3". This must be the cell where you have the data validation drop-down.

This code will run whenever *Trigger* is changed. You make a selection there and the VLOOKUP function will find the quantity in column 2 of the `Products` range. If the item isn't found in the list it will return 0 but you can set the cell validation to prevent the entry of an item that isn't in the list. The code will add one to the quantity found and issue the result in `.Offset(0, 1)`, meaning one column to the right of the *Trigger* cell.

You might want to do other things with your idea. I think the system I suggest can be adapted to whatever you have in mind, including changing the quantity in the `Products` list.